# How to store state in an Android Service

Tags: android, service, state

I'd like to make my `IntentService` remember when it was called last time and how many times it was called so far. It doesn't matter if these values are reset when the phone is rebooted, but they must not be reset when the application process is killed.

Should I store these state variables in a `SharedPreferences`, or is there is a better and/or more lightweight way? I tried `intent.getExtras()`, but it seems that the values I put there are not remembered between calls.

Answer (score 3):

For persistent storage like this, `SharedPreferences` is usually the way to go. And don't forget to do `commit()` after editing the preference.